# Declarations in Textbox but execution in button

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition. (Refer pic for problem) My problem is that how would I convert it using button? Because I put the codes under the textbox since the declarations should be there. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: That code is nonsense and so is the question.  "Integer" is a string and can never be `-3` or any other numeric value

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry, Im new in VB. Just highschooler. What do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: The line `Select Case "Integer"` is wrong.